# How to remove object from react-hook-form state

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am working on form layout for multiple children. Each child will have its own data about their name, surname,phone and email.

[image: form with multiple children]

My data structure for each child looks like this.

```
[id]:{
   name:"",
   surname:"",
   phone:""
   email:""
}
```

I am changing between child using  unregister with keepValue:true. Where selectedChildId is the active child with dark gray bg.

```
useEffect(() => {
    unregister(selectedChildId, { keepValue: true });
}, [selectedChildId]);
```

This way I can jump between children without needing to save their state anywhere else.

Everything works fine, but if I delete a child, the react hook form still keeps the child object with empty string values and I dont want that. Is there any way of removing a specific value (object) from react hook form state?

Comment: you should check `useFieldArray` https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/

Comment: But what name would I have there?